# Is there a closed form of $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{|S_{1}(n,k)|}{k!}z^{k} $?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, closed-form, stirling-numbers

So far, I have [found](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3902) (p. 5) the following generating functions of the unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind:

$$ \sum_{l=1}^{n} |S_{1}(n,l)|z^{l} = (z)_{n} = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (z+k) , $$ and $$ \sum_{n=l}^{\infty} \frac{|S_{1}(n,l)|}{n!}z^{n} = (-1)^{l} \frac{\ln^{l}(1-z)}{l!} .$$

Instead of summing the latter expression over $n$, I'm curious whether there is a closed form of the generating sum when summed over the other indices:

$$ f(z) := \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{|S_{1}(n,k)|}{k!}z^{k} .$$ One could also take the sum from $k=1$ to $k=\infty$, as $|S_{1}(n,k)| = 0$ when $k>n$.

> **Question**: is there a closed form or succinct formula for $f(\cdot)$ ?

Both derivations and references would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is hard to imagine that a polynomial can have a more "closed" form. At best it can have a special name (such as Chebyshev).

Comment: @user Perhaps I should rephrase the question. You do see what I intend to ask, no?

Comment: Not quite. But of course one can investigate if the roots of the polynomial have a simple closed form.

Comment: @user I consider the evaluations of the first two generating functions above as closed forms, and I wonder whether $f(\cdot)$ has a closed form in that sense as well. Do you think this is not a reasonable question to ask? (That question of mine was not rhetorical, I am genuinely curious as to where the confusion stems from)

Comment: I would not say that your question is unreasonable, but a polynomial is usually considered as a closed form, though in some very special cases there may exist a simpler non-polynomial form (as in the case of the geometric progression sum).

Comment: @user Right. We could compare this example with the first generating function. Over there, the sum on the left is also a polynomial. But on the right it's a polynomial that does not involve the stirling numbers anymore, so I guess one could argue that it is in a certain sense a simpler representation of the sum on the left. It is in that sense - no stirling numbers, and as simple as possible - that I'm looking for a closed form of the similar-looking function $f(\cdot)$

Comment: The rhs of the first example is still a polynomial - with rather special roots.

Comment: @user indeed, I am looking for an exact expression of these roots. That allows us to write a product expression of the polynomial in closed form.

Comment: Then probably you should directly ask about the roots of the polynomial. I would not expect any nice expression. Particularly starting with $n=12$ the polynomial has besides real also non-real roots.

Comment: @user Alright, I should probably amend what I said earlier. I am interested in either a closed form of the roots, or a simpler non-polynomial form (if it exists - akin to the geometric progression sum)

Comment: You can write $$
f(z) = \frac{1}{{2\pi {\rm i}}}\int_{ - \infty }^{(0 + )} {{\rm e}^{zt} \left( {\frac{1}{t}} \right)_n \frac{{{\rm d}t}}{t}} 
$$ but I do not think it helps.